# Django/Wagtail Deployment on Digital Ocean destroys admin session when navigating

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, digital-ocean, wagtail

Experienced with other cloud hosting providers I tried Digital Ocean the first time to set up a Wagtail app (should be a staging/production environment with pipeline in the future). Following [this tutorial](https://docs.digitalocean.com/tutorials/app-deploy-django-app/) (but just deploying a SQLite database not a solid one), everything works fine. The app will be understand as a Python app when cloning it from GitHub and the default build process (by Python Buildpack) followed by running with Gunicorn server will be executed like expacted – there is no Dockerfile provided. Afterwards the frontend works as expected when first opening it. The admin panel allows to enter but when navigating to page editing it destroys the session and I´m faced with the login panel – probably auto logout, since expired session. The django-admin reacts the same way.

The tutorial uses get_random_secret_key. Maybe this is not accepted by Digital Ocean? Another maybe important information is that the set-cookie header first contains a expiry date in one year (like it is set). But after the session was destroyed it´s set to 1970 (probably something like a null value). Actually this is just the indicator for the forced ended session I guess.

Since it´s not so easy to find out, if it´s something which has to do with the code or safety measurements I didn´t share code. But I can do that of course, if it´s needed. It´s probably a issue not just for me and a hiint which is the cause could help other developers struggeling with this, too.

Comment: I'd guess that the SQLite database is the problem here: sessions are stored in the database, SQLite databases exist on the filesystem, and the filesystem isn't persistent, so session data is liable to be lost with no warning.

Comment: Did you set the environment variable? https://docs.digitalocean.com/tutorials/app-deploy-django-app/#:~:text=Warning,password%20generator.

Comment: @gasman The cause lies obviously in the SQLite db. Thanks. It works now.

Comment: @RichardAllen The (from the tutorial) requested ones and DEVELOPMENT_MODE=False.